# Querying Winston Logs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) for logging in a node.js application.

I see there are options to [query](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#querying-logs) it.

The example shows how to use options from and to.

My question is

1. What are the other options ?
2. How do I specify what file should be queried ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this same problem.

At least some of the options can be found in [Winston's transport.js](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/transport.js) in the function Transport.prototype.normalizeQuery.

Here's a quick summary:

> options.rows, options.limit = how many results to return. default is
>   10;
>
> options.start = starting row offset. default is 0
>
> options.from = date string or date object for starting limit.
>   default is now -24 hours
>
> options.until = date string or date object for ending limit. default
>   is now
>
> options.order =  either 'asc' or 'desc' order. default is 'desc'
>
> options.fields = which fields to return. default is undefined (which
>   returns all)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of querying file logger + available options. The main drawback (IMO) is lack of filtering. The most useful feature would be filtering by level but alas...

```js
"use strict";

var logFilename = __dirname + '/log/2014-02-24.log';

var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            filename:  logFilename,
            timestamp: true
        })
    ]
});

var options = {
    from:   new Date - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    until:  new Date,
    limit:  10,
    start:  0,
    order:  'asc',
    fields: ['message']
};
logger.query(options, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log(result);
});
```

P.S. BTW, here's an [open issue](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/issues/367) about querying logs.