# node.js winston query log in file

Tags: node.js, file, logging, winston

I have been using `winston` for my logging in node.js projects, which log onto files (thanks to `winston-daily-rotate-file`). Now I want to have a better monitoring to those logged files by querying them. Do I have to self-implement a tool that reads and parses files, or `winston` already supports a querying mechanism?

Comment: It seems that winston already include a query tool. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21978915/1985912.

Comment: @Striped It doesn't seem to work. I have to utilize something to run and parse logs separately from the current app which produces logs :(